# Better way to view windows certs than MMC?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, certificate, mmc

I'm trying to view the windows certs on my box but the UI for certmgr and MMC is terrible. Specifically, I'd like a quick way to view and compare thumbprints and friendly names. Does anyone know a better tool to do this?

Doesn't have to be a GUI, I'm ok with console commands if they work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a powershell script that makes it super easy to find certs by thumbprint, subject names or serial numbers.

It will search "CurrentUser" and "LocalMachine" cert stores by default and will do a loose case insensitive match on thumbprint, subject names and the serial number. You can also add -PrivateKey to list only certs with a private key and -expiration to list certs by expiration date. Except for when using the -expiration flag, it will return a list of actual .NET X509Certificate objects that you can manipulate.

Usage examples:

> get-cert a909
>
> get-cert contoso -privateKey

it also adds two aliases: lscert, dircert

```
function Get-Cert {
  param (
    [string]$filter,
    [string]$thumbprint,
    [string]$subject,
    [string]$altName,
    [string]$serialNumber,
    [switch]$expiration,
    [switch]$privateKey,
    [string[]]$certDirectoryOverride,
    [string[]]$localFolders
    )
  $certDirectories  = "cert:\CurrentUser\My", "cert:\LocalMachine\My"

  # Set the cert store to list from
  $certStores = $certDirectories
  if ($certDirectoryOverride -ne $null) {
    $certStores = $certDirectoryOverride
  }

  $items = @()
  # get all certs from the stores
  foreach ($store in $certStores) {
    $items += ls $store
  }

  if ($localFolders) {
    foreach ($folder in $localFolders) {
      $localCertPaths = ls -path $folder -i *cer -rec
      foreach ($certPath in $localCertPaths) {
        $fullName = $certPath.FullName
        $directoryName = $certPath.DirectoryName
        $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certPath)
        add-member -InputObject $cert -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PSParentPath -Value $directoryName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        add-member -InputObject $cert -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $fullName
        add-member -InputObject $cert -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $fileName

        $items += $cert;
      }
    }
  }

  # add handy expiration property
  $items | %{
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Expiration -Value {[DateTime]$this.GetExpirationDateString()} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Path -Value PSPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileName -Value PSPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Value {
      return ($this.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "subject alternative name"}).Format(1).Replace("`r`n",", ").Replace("DNS Name=","")
    }
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name AlternateNames -Value SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name AlternativeNames -Value SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name SubjectAlternativeNames -Value SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name SubjectAltNames -Value SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    add-member -InputObject $_ -MemberType AliasProperty -Name AltNames -Value SubjectAlternateNames -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }

  # filter all the certs
  if ($filter -ne $null) {
    $items = $items | where-object {
      ($_.Thumbprint -match $filter) -or
      ($_.Subject -match $filter) -or
      ($_.SerialNumber -match $filter) -or
      ($_.SubjectAlternateName -match $filter)
      }
  }
  if ($thumbprint -ne $null) {
    $items = $items | where {$_.Thumbprint -match $thumbprint}
  }
  if ($subject -ne $null) {
    $items = $items | where {$_.Subject -match $subject}
  }
  if ($altName -ne $null) {
    $items = $items | where {$_.SubjectAlternateNames -match $altName}
  }
  if ($serialNumber -ne $null) {
    $items = $items | where {$_.SerialNumber -match $serialNumber}
  }
  if ($privateKey) {
    $items = $items | where {$_.PrivateKey -ne $null}
  }

  if ($expiration) {
    return $items | sort expiration | ft expiration, thumbprint, subject
  }

  return $items
}

new-alias lscert Get-Cert -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
new-alias dircert Get-Cert -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 6):

You can open a Powershell console and use the dir command on the Cert: provider to list the information you want. For example, the commands below would list thumbprints and subjects (friendly names) for the current user certs and the machine certs respectively:

```
dir Cert:\CurrentUser\My
ls Cert:\LocalMachine\My\
```

You can run the command below to get more info on how to work with certificates using the Certificate provider in Powershell.

```
help certificate
```

Or you can read more online [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847761(v=wps.630).aspx)

Comment: Subject name is not the same as Friendly name.

Comment: additional information: you can also set your location to Cert with `Set-Location Cert:` and then handle it like a normal windows drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VBS script like:

```
Dim store 
Set store = CreateObject("CAPICOM.Store")

WScript.Echo "Dumping local Root CAs:"
store.Open , "Root", 0  ' or "My" or "CA"
For Each cert In store.CERTIFICATES
     WScript.Echo cert.SubjectName
     'WScript.Echo cert.SerialNumber  
     WScript.Echo cert.Thumbprint   
     WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"         
Next
WScript.Echo "============================================================================="

WScript.Echo "Dumping Personal CAs:"
store.Open , "CA", 0  
For Each cert In store.CERTIFICATES
     WScript.Echo cert.SubjectName
     'WScript.Echo cert.SerialNumber  
     WScript.Echo cert.Thumbprint   
     WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"         
Next
WScript.Echo "============================================================================="

WScript.Echo "Dumping Personal certificates:"
store.Open , "My", 0 
For Each cert In store.CERTIFICATES
     WScript.Echo cert.SubjectName
     'WScript.Echo cert.SerialNumber  
     WScript.Echo cert.Thumbprint   
     WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"         
Next
```

Copy the code in a file called dumpcerts.vbs and execute

```
cscript dumpcerts.vbs
```